# FFMPEG code (Not command) to stream audio to a Multicast address

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, udp, multicast

I need to stream a audio to a Multicast address.  And I konw the command could be:

> *ffmpeg -i input -f mpegts
>   udp://hostname:port?pkt_size=188&buffer_size=65535*

But i don't konw how to do this via code? Can you help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not different from any other video conversion with ffmpeg - open input stream, open output stream, and loop around av_read_packet, av_decode_video, av_encode_video, av_write_packet_interleaved.

The easiest way would be to reap apart the `ffmpeg` utility source code, which is in `ffmpeg.c` in the ffmpeg source directory.